# Can we use "then" before the main verb? "... we'll then go."

Tags: adverbs

> Each page takes less than a minute to produce, although for colour pages four versions, once each for black, cyan, magenta and yellow are sent. The pages are **then** processed into photographic negatives and the film is used to produce aluminium printing plates ready for the presses. [ROBOTS AT WORK](http://www.ielts-mentor.com/reading-sample/gt-reading/76-general-training-reading-sample-8)

but I'm always use *then* between to phrases (when it is mean: next or after that).

> Let me finish this job, **then** we'll go.

My question is: Can we use it before tha man verb?

> Let me finish this job, we'll **then** go.

Comment: Yes. Your own example sounds a little awkward, but I think it's because of an unrelated point (which is that I would want to know, "we'll then go *where*").

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - With "then we'll go", period, I'd asked where to too. So to me, it's the context, not the placement of "then", which is irrelevant - again, to me personally;)

Comment: Maybe it's a dialect or regional thing, but "...then we'll go." sounds fine to this native NYC speaker.  To me, it just means "then we'll leave this place."

Comment: @stangdon - So it does to me. I only meant that if you feel like asking "where to", the placement of "then" is not the thing that got you focused upon it:)

Comment: @Rompey, stangdon, so then we'll all agree to agree :D?

Comment: @stangdon, Rompey, so then we'll all agree to agree :D?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - Personally, always respecting opinions different to mine, I don't see anything here to agree to disagree upon. Have a nice day:-)

Comment: @Rompey, heh, that was the point of my comment, that is, we were all saying the same thing :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adverbs of time can be [placed](https://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/AdverbPl.html) at the start of a sentence, after an auxiliary verb/modal, before a main verb or at the end of a sentence:

Soon we must make decision
we must soon make a decision
we must make a decision soon.

With so many choices of location, even small things affect the placement. In the case of your sentence, one of the things that may affect it is the rhythm. For this meaning, the word **then** must be a strong syllable, and in the first sentence **go** is also a strong syllable, giving a nice rhythm.

> Let me finish this job, **then** we'll **go**.

The second sentence also requires **go** to be a strong syllable, which puts two strong syllables next to each other: we generally avoid this rhythm if possible.

> Let me finish this job: we'll **then** **go**.

If we add some more information, for example a *where* clause, **go** loses its stress, which moves to the *where* clause, and we find this rhythm much more comfortable.

> Let me finish this job: we'll **then** go and get **some**thing to **eat**.

Answer (score 1):

> Let me finish this job, then we'll go.
>
> Let me finish this job, we'll then go.

I think, that "then" can go in either place; although I think most people would tend to put it at the start of the sentence. And I'd write it as two separate sentences, or use a semicolon after "job":

> Let me finish this job. Then we'll go.
>
> Let me finish this job; we'll then go.

[See the Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+will+then+go%2Cthen+we+will+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwe%20will%20then%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthen%20we%20will%20go%3B%2Cc0).